# How to check whether a List contains null in Kotlin?

Tags: java, collections, kotlin

I'm having trouble understanding why

```
class Main {
    private val outputStreams: List<OutputStream>

    @JvmOverloads constructor(outputStreams: List<OutputStream> = LinkedList()) {
        if(outputStreams.contains(null)) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("outputStreams mustn't contain null")
        }
        this.outputStreams = outputStreams
    }
}
```

causes the compilation error `...Main.kt:[12,26] Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.`.

If I use `outputStreams.contains(null as OutputStream))` the compilation succeeds, but `Main(LinkedList<OutputStream>())` fails at runtime due to

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type java.io.OutputStream
    at kotlinn.collection.contains.nulll.check.Main.<init>(Main.kt:12)
    at kotlinn.collection.contains.nulll.check.MainTest.testInit(MainTest.kt:13)
```

which leaves me with no other approach for keeping the code as close to the original Java as possible which is my intend as well as understanding this issue as it is rather than searching for a workaround.

Comment: Try `@JvmOverloads constructor(outputStreams: List<OutputStream?> = LinkedList())`.

By placing a "?" you're telling the compiler that the list might contain a null value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the compiler, the parameter `outputStreams` cannot contain `null` as its type is `List<OutputStream>` as opposed to `List<OutputStream?>`. The type system does not expect `null` to be inside this list, thus no need to check it.

*On the other hand*, **IF** that parameter actually could contain `null` (since it comes from a Java caller) you should mark it as nullable explicitly: `List<OutputStream?>`

Comment: Wow, is there anything that Kotlin doesn't handle as smart as possible?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I would add that given the `@JvmOverloads` annotation this is likely being used from Java, so technically the type system can no longer guarantee the list does not contain null. If you instantiated this from Java with `Collections.<OutputStream>singletonList(null)` it would still compile but fail at runtime. If you know it will be used from Java, you could follow @ToraCode's suggestion and declare the types as `List<OutputStream?>`, but only if you really need `IllegalArgumentException` specifically. Otherwise I'd just allow the NPE to be thrown and avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

I belive that the answer is `List<OutputStream?>`. `?` will make your list can contain `null`. 
Check the doc: [enter link description here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)

Answer (score 1):

filterNotNull() method can filter out all null objects from the collection so you could use the code below.
Obviously, you need to inform the compiler that objects in the collection are nullable.
I changed the OutputStream type to String for easier testing.

```
    class Main{
private val outputStreams: List<String?>

@JvmOverloads constructor(outputStreams: List<String?> = LinkedList()) {

    if(outputStreams.filterNotNull().size < outputStreams.size) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("outputStreams mustn't contain null")
    }
    this.outputStreams = outputStreams
}

fun getOutputStream(): List<String?>{
    return outputStreams
}
 }
```

A second approach would be to use let  T.let(block: (T) -> R): R where you would accept the nullable object, but then you would have to check whether there is any "null" string and react accordingly.

```
    class Main{
lateinit var outputStreams: List<String?>

@JvmOverloads constructor(outputStreams: List<String?> = LinkedList()) {

    outputStreams.let {
        this.outputStreams = outputStreams
    }

}

fun getOutputStream(): List<String?>{
    return outputStreams
}
}

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val outputStreamWithNull: List<String?> = listOf("alpha", "beta", null, "omega")
val mainA = Main(outputStreamWithNull)


mainA.getOutputStream().forEach {
    println(it)
}

}
```

If you are "confident" that the object parameter in the constructor should be a collection of non-null objects, then you can remove ?
However, the nullable check on the List collection must be done by an object initialising Main class, so you would basically move the responsibility of catching NullPointerException to someone else.